# Number of occurances of all elements in very big set

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, element

I have got an set of about 500.123 elements 
(IP addresses generated by command:

```
conntrack -L | awk '{ printf $4 "\n" }' | cut -d'=' -f2 )
```

I need to get 20 elements (with number of occurrences) from this set whitch are occuring most.

How to do this in optimum way?

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing my question looks clear @Cyrus

Comment: Append `| sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 20`?

Comment: The output is ipaddresses only. Each addres in one line.
Nothing more...

Comment: @Cyrus It works I didn't know that there is a -c parameter in uniq. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `print $4` is a lot better than `printf $4"\n"`, since it won't get you into trouble if `$4` happens to contain a `%`.

Comment: @rici so how to get one address per line?

Comment: @marioBash: `print` does that.

Comment: Sorry didnt notice difference earlier.

Comment: The point is that you should never use an uncontrolled string as a format argument to printf, *in any language*.